# Excel VBA install add-in

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I use this code to install an Add-in. But it does not seem to enable it. I get this error message:

> Runtime error 1004: Unable to set the installed property of the add-in
>   class.

My code:

```
Sub installatie_Click()

    Dim AI As Excel.AddIn
    Set AI = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="J:\Planning\Sjablonen\Updates\versieA.xlam")

    Application.AddIns("versieA").Installed = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried only with `Application.AddIns("versieA").Installed = True`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns what is the difference between your code and my last line of code?

Comment: I guess the line that arises the error is `Set AI = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="J:\Planning\Sjablonen\Updates\versieA.xlam")`. I've got another add-ins in my machine, and to activate them my sub is just one line (`Application.AddIns("versieA").Installed = True`). I mean deleting the `Dim` and `Set`parts

Comment: Right, i tried it but i got the same error message.

Comment: You got the same error but on a different line? have you checked the add-in name is properly installed, enabled? (sometimes excel bloks some add-ins).

Comment: I found out that my file was corrupted, I made a new file and now it is working. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I always use to make my adding able to self install. Please try this code (in addin `Workbook_Open` event of its `ThisWorkbook` module):
 Your file may have a problem...
 You have to set its Title (`BuiltinDocumentProperties(1)`). Manually, right click on the addin file and modify (only with adding closed) or  programatically (`ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(1) = "Whatever"`), but without spaces..

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim Name As String, tmp As Boolean, n As Boolean, Merk As String
   Name = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(1)
   On Error Resume Next
   tmp = AddIns(Name).Installed
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
      Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
         If Workbooks.Count = 0 Then n = True
             If n Then
                 Workbooks.Add
                 Merk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
             End If
             AddIns.Add Filename:=ThisWorkbook.FullName
             AddIns(Name).Installed = True
             If n Then Workbooks(Merk).Close False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```